# is it possible to control page's css through django-admin?

Tags: css, django, django-admin

In my blog, I can create different category pages and I want to have different body css for each one of them. Thing is I only have one template, category.html which means the css I work here will affect every categories. is it possible to control page's css through django-admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check current category in your template and based on your current category you can load a css file.

```
{% if current_category == "1" %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="category1.css">
{% elif current_category == "2" %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="category2.css">
{% endif %}
```